# How can I format a number as xxx-xx-xxxx?

Tags: oracle, string-formatting, to-char

I am querying social security number data from a stored procedure and I would like to format it as a social security number in my stored procedure.

How can I format xxxxxxxxx like xxx-xx-xxxx in Oracle?

Comment: Is it stored as a VARCHAR or a NUMBER. If the latter, how are you dealing with leading zeros.

Answer (score 17):

**SSN formatting with TO_CHAR**

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(012345678, '000g00g0000','nls_numeric_characters=.-') ssn from dual;

SSN
-----------
012-34-5678
```

**update:** thanks to Gary for pointing out that the '0' format character should be used rather than the '9' to preserve leading zeroes.

Comment: +1, Oracle SQL programmers should become familiar with the formatting tools Oracle provides.

Comment: That fails if the nine digit form of the SSN has leading zeroes.

select TO_CHAR(23456789, 'fm000g00g0000','nls_numeric_characters=.-') ssn from dual;

Answer (score 11):

you could also use the concat operator `||`, which might be more readable.

```
 SUBSTR(data, 1, 3) ||'-'||SUBSTR(data, 4, 2)||'-'||SUBSTR(data, 6, 4)
```

Comment: Looks good and works if the data is character. If it is integer, then 7/8 digits (ie with leading 0 in the 9 digit form) would convert incorrectly

Comment: I have a hard time believing this will ever be more readable than the to_char solution. Besides which, if the value to be formatted is the result of an expression or the return value of a function, wouldn't this cause redundant calls/calculations?

Answer (score 5):

And if you'd like to check if the number consists of 9 digits before applying the format, then regular expressions can be of help:

```
SQL> create table t (nr)
  2  as
  3  select 123456789 from dual union all
  4  select 987654321 from dual union all
  5  select null from dual union all
  6  select 1234567 from dual union all
  7  select 12345678901234 from dual
  8  /

Tabel is aangemaakt.

SQL> select nr
  2       , regexp_replace(nr,'(^[[:digit:]]{3})([[:digit:]]{2})([[:digit:]]{4}$)','\1-\2-\3') formatted_nr
  3    from t
  4  /

                                    NR FORMATTED_NR
-------------------------------------- --------------------
                             123456789 123-45-6789
                             987654321 987-65-4321

                               1234567 1234567
                        12345678901234 12345678901234

5 rijen zijn geselecteerd.
```

Regards,
Rob.

Comment: nice example of creating a demo table and also regular expressions!

Answer (score 0):

```
CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(SUBSTR(sspdata, 1, 3), '-'), SUBSTR(sspdata, 4, 2)), '-',) SUBSTR(sspdata, 6, 4))
```

Comment: And there you have why I hate formatting stuff in most SQL dialects. Heinous!

Comment: I'm 4 years late to the party, but is there a good reason to use `CONCAT` over `||` ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm only 11 years late, but I came to this question a few months ago and just figured out my new preferred method:

```
replace(to_char(my_number, 'FM000,00,0000'), ',', '-')
```

The `FM` trims the leading space, and the `replace()` turns those commas into dashes. One caveat: This only works for numbers (which is fine in our use-cases).

It's more elegant than `substr()` and more compact (and easier to remember, in my opinion) than `nls_numeric_characters` method.

That said, I assume this method is less efficient than the `nls_numeric_characters` method.